# In MVVM should the setter of a property contains other methods or logic?

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

In MVVM design pattern, of the properties that are binded to the view, should they only have "dumb" setters that updates an internal value?

Or is it ok to have other methods or logic within it that updates other parts of the viewmodel?

If that is the case, should any action from the screen be routed through an action only?

For example:
I have a toggle button in which its "IsChecked" property is binded to a property in my viewmodels.

Should I handle the action separately than the property changed by creating a command, or can I used the setter of the "IsChecked" property to handle custom logic?

Comment: all i can say is ***it depends***. usually property setters in MVVM contains a method for invoking property changed notifications using `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. it may have more methods as needed.

Comment: **Primarily Opinion Based.** - but yes, you can add whatever logic to your setters (or call to other methods containing the logic) that's ok.

Comment: Ok - I'm just shooting for best practices here